# When sending form-data, req.file null comes to the server, I use express-fileupload, next.js, antd form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, antd

i try to submit form-data, req.body comes but req.files is null. I use antd form

sending request from UI

```
function* workCreateUser({ payload }: PayloadAction<ICreateUser>): any {
  let formData = new FormData()
  
  formData.append('picture', JSON.stringify(payload.picture.file))
  formData.append('login', payload.login)
  formData.append('name', payload.name)
  formData.append('color', payload.color)
 
  const response = yield call(() =>
    fetch(`${URL_SERVER}api/users`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
  )
}
```

API:

```
class UserController {
  async create(req, res) {
    try {
      console.log('req.body******', req.body)
      console.log('req.files', req.files)
      const user = await UserService.create(req.body, req.body.picture)
      res.json(user)
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json(e)
    }
  }
```

ps  I included fileUpload

`app.use(fileUpload({}))`

and forgot to say that everything works through the postman

my image comes in body and not in files

[payload.picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui7Qw.png)

[and here is what comes to the server:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W6WC.png)

[this is what comes to the server when sent via postman:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlZen.png)

Comment: Probably because you're attempting to JSON encode what I assume is binary file data. What exactly does `payload.picture.file` contain?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_FIVEveOYkghDpKEBG6wo72x9WXOGqOh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, and here is what comes to the server: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QabfEU2YS2QVZyfF7PqIWYTKA1XrjP3e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i55ZbMwJ9uLQvoV1Doe8Kyo6-749RXLL/view?usp=sharing   
this is what comes to the server when sent via postman

Comment: Sorry - I make it a policy not to click links like that. Please add relevant information to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, 
I added screenshots to the question, thanks for helping me!

Comment: to  upload file to server use npm multer